# Passing table name to function Dynamically as Input parameter and using it

Tags: sql, function, cursor, greenplum

In the below function I am passing in my table name as text 'K' and wish to use it for cursor declaration inside my function.I am using postgres 8.2 (greenplum)

I used `quote_ident(k)`, dint work either. Could some one help me out. THanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vin_temp(K text) RETURNS text AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        r vin_res%rowtype;
        r1 numeric default 0;

        rfr numeric default 0;
        rdu numeric default 0;
        rav numeric default 0;

        rfr1 numeric default 0;
        rdu1 numeric default 0;
        rav1 numeric default 0;


        r2 numeric default 0;
        i integer default 0;
        x  text default '';
        curs2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM k order by week_end asc;
    BEGIN

    open curs2;
      LOOP
      FETCH curs2 INTO r;
      exit when not found;

         if (i=1) then
          r1:=r.v1;
          rav:=r.v2;
          rfr:=r.v3;
          else 
          some logic here
          end if;

        END LOOP;
        RETURN 'yes';
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

i tried the following code as well :

```
curs2 CURSOR FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * from '||quote_ident(k)||' order by week_end asc';
```

Comment: @Houari Cant use that method as am on version postgres 8.2 . I get the error " prepared statement "format" does not exist "

Answer (score 0):

An **unbound cursor** must be used for dynamic queries.
It is described in documentation for version 8.2 :
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html

> **37.8.2.2. OPEN FOR EXECUTE**
>
> OPEN unbound_cursor FOR EXECUTE query_string;
>
> The cursor variable is opened and given the specified query to execute. The cursor cannot be open already, and **it must have been declared as an unbound cursor** (that is, as a simple refcursor variable). The query is specified as a string expression, in the same way as in the EXECUTE command. As usual, this gives flexibility so the query can vary from one run to the next.
>
> An example:
>
> OPEN curs1 FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident($1);

(emphasis mine)
Here is a working example, please take a look at this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/a0d8a/1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vin_temp(K text) RETURNS int 
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  curs1 refcursor;
  x int;
begin
  OPEN curs1 FOR EXECUTE 'Select Sum( x ) From ' || $1;
  Fetch curs1 Into x;
  Close curs1;
  Return x;
End
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
/
```